# How can I have different routines fire off at different intervals

Tags: esp32, loop

I'm making an interface that will have a digital clock....once a second..

I'd like to do other things at different intervals but if I `delay(1000)` then I have to wait that second which is now the minimum other things have to run at.

Comment: this has been asked over and over ... study the `blinkWithoutDelay` example sketch in the arduino IDE and please, do some research ... akso look into FSM (finite state machine)

Comment: You can also Google and research "nonblocking cooperative multitasking." I've written about it pretty extensively in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50032992/4561887. Start with [Blink Without Delay](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/BlinkWithoutDelay) though first to get the gist of the concept.

Comment: https://github.com/jandrassy/KitchenTimerClock/blob/master/KitchenTimerClock/KitchenTimerClock.ino

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments: you should read up on State Machines and have a close look at the [Blink Without Delay example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/BlinkWithoutDelay).

To get you started with an example closer to what you want to achieve, have a look at the code below; it will count seconds without blocking the loop.

```cpp
unsigned long int secondsTimerMillis;
int seconds, minutes, hours = 0;
int secondsInterval = 1000; //ms

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // More setup() stuff goes here
  secondsTimerMillis = 0; 
}

void loop() {
  if ((millis() - secondsTimerMillis) >= secondsInterval) {
    seconds++;
    secondsTimerMillis = millis();
    Serial.println(seconds);
    // More stuff you want to do every second goes here
  }
  // More loop() stuff goes here
}
```

This is just the basic mechanism, and it won't be very accurate without some way of adjusting the clock every now and again.

You will also have to add code for checking `seconds == 60` and increase `minutes` / reset `seconds` when needed; the same goes for hours.

Having/handling other events at other intervals is just more of the same.

Note that using a Real Time Clock as the basis for your timing would make your <strike>life</strike> programming much easier, and your clock more accurate, but I am assuming you want to do this "by hand".

Answer (score 0):

If you want a clock, your best option is... to buy a clock. Or, more
precisely, an RTC module. Not only will it be way more accurate than
your Arduino, it will also be able to keep the time off battery when
your project is powered off.

If you really want to rely on the (unreliable) timing capabilities of
your Arduino, you may want to try the `millis()`-based fake RTC provided
by the [Adafruit RTClib](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib) library: [RTC_Millis](https://adafruit.github.io/RTClib/html/class_r_t_c___millis.html). Example
usage:

```cpp
#include <RTClib.h>

RTC_Millis clock;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    clock.begin(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
}

void loop() {
    static DateTime last_time;
    DateTime now = clock.now();
    if (now != last_time) {
        char buffer[] = "hh:mm:ss";
        Serial.println(now.toString(buffer));
        last_time = now;
    }
}
```

Note the test `if (now != last_time)`, which is equivalent to the test
`if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval)` of the Blink Without
Delay tutorial (the RTC has a resolution of one second). It allows the
code to be non-blocking.

Note also that, if you are willing to measure you clock's drift rate,
you could calibrate-out that drift by using [RTC_micros](https://adafruit.github.io/RTClib/html/class_r_t_c___micros.html) instead,
and calling the `adjustDrift()` method in `setup()`.